# Sending email via Intent.createChooser. Works but returns to different Activity

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I have and app which requires sending emails with attachments.
This app contains many activities. Within one activity, I send an email using the following intent:
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email"), EMAIL_REQUEST);

This works fine. The email is sent.
(note: onActivityResult is never called. I can live with this, it's not important)

The problem:

After email is sent, the app loads/goes to the startup/initial activity, not the activity from which the email was sent.

How can I return to the activity which sent the email?

Some observations:
I added some Toast(s) to the onRestart, onPause, and onCreate methods of the startup/initial activity. After the email is sent, the startup activity is displayed but none of the events are called.

Comment: If you want to send an email, then return to the previous activity in the stack, you can simply call `finish();` after sending the email.

Comment: I did some more testing. It appears that onResume was indeed being called on the startup activity. Adding a startactivity here to show the desired activity did work. Although, your solution is better. I'll give it a try. Thank-you.

Comment: You are welcome, added my comment as an answer. If this was helpful, please tick it as accepted answer. Happy coding!

Comment: Please post your manifest. The behaviour you are describing is not normal and is indicative of something bad.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send an email, then return to the previous activity in the stack, you can simply call `finish();` when you are done sending the email. This will finish the current `Activity`, and return to the second-top `Activity` in the stack.

Update:

Add this code after your email has been sent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Marcus, it doesn't work. It kills the activity I want to return to.

Comment: Okay, I might have read the question wrong. But if you want to navigate to a particular Activity after your email are being sent, you could do so using an Intent. See my updated answer. @AngeloCarzis

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. What was happening in my case is that when I called the email Intent from within my activity, the activities `OnPause` was being called. The problem was that at the end of the OnPause function code I had a `finish()`, which was causing the activity to be destroyed !

Removing `finish()` fixed the problem, although I do think I still have some work to do, because I think I was calling `finish()` to pass bundle information back to the calling activity. I will have to see about that later...